# Grails Gorm Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

> Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 10 seconds, none available[size:7; busy:0; idle:0; lastwait:10000]

The above error is coming after a long time my application gets live.

Below is my GORM db configuration:

```
propertyShortSlave:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: url
    username: uuuuuu
    password: pppppp
    dbCreate: validate
    readOnly: true
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    properties:
            initialSize: 5
            maxActive: 7
            minIdle: 5
            validationQuery: SELECT 1
            maxIdle: 7
            maxWait: 10000
            maxAge: 600000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
            validationQueryTimeout: 3
            validationInterval: 15000
            testOnBorrow: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            testOnReturn: false
            jdbcInterceptors: "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried reconnect=true on url ?   url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?autoReconnect=true" difficult to say since  you have not defined url....

Comment: i have tried this , but without validationQuery property. In that case the connections gets closed very soon. But i havenot tried autoReconnect with validationQuery

Comment: https://github.com/vahidhedayati/kchat/blob/master/grails-app/conf/kchatConfig.groovy#L13-L31 I had this config running in production with no issue  validationQuery="SELECT 1" must be set for it to keep connection open.

Comment: it means i should not provide maxActive and maxIdle number.

Comment: but without these numbers , how can we control number of connections.It may make a lot of connections and slow the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these:

```
dataSource {
....
 url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&CharSet=UTF-8&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
....
properties {
 ....
 validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
 ....
 }
}
```

Comment: You are posting in JSON format, actually, it is in YAML format. But the idea is correct.

Comment: This is the groovy closures used by Grails in 2.x version. YAML introduces after Grails 3.x

Comment: Correct, I'm just making a note for question's author because different formats could be confusing for a newbie.

Comment: @Jeeveshpandey, i haven't tried this result yet, because now my connections are working fine, but when the issue arises again i'll apply this solution.For now i just increased the number of maxActive Connections to 20.Lets see how it works.